# Bootstrap overwrites column on mobile with .row>* (all child columns)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling quite a bit with an issue with bootstrap. There seems to be no information on this topic when I search on google.

The thing is that my col-sm-6 classes get overwritten by this piece of code:

```
.row>* {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}
```

This is how the column is nested:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12"> 
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Practically it does not even get overwritten since the column class completely disappears from my inspector. Anyone out there who can explain this issue?

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="stap-3"> <!-- STAP 3 blok -->
                    <div class="stappen-block">
                        <div class="text-stappen">
                        <h1>STAP 3: Kies Bladen, spoelbak en kraan</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed auctor cras est, amet
                            quis in. Semper vitae ultricies commodo et, commodo vitae in ut nulla. Tellus
                            sapien sed elementum, eu et ut ac nisi ut. Nam urna porta turpis turpis volutpat
                            ac pellentesque suscipit. Porta feugiat a in urna.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class="bladen-genre">Bladen</h3>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex">
                                <div class="bladen-item selected">
                                    <img class="bladen-img" src="images/licht-beton.png">
                                    <span class="bladen-title">Licht Beton</span>
                                    <div class="bladen-info">
                                        <span class="bladen-pricem1">€130,- per m1</span><br>
                                        <span class="bladen-amount">Benodigde m1: 2.3m1</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €135,-</span>
                                    <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex">
                                <div class="bladen-item">
                                    <img class="bladen-img" src="images/donker-beton.png">
                                    <span class="bladen-title">Donker Beton</span>
                                    <div class="bladen-info">
                                        <span class="bladen-pricem1">€130,- per m1</span><br>
                                        <span class="bladen-amount">Benodigde m1: 2.3m1</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €135,-</span>
                                    <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex">
                                <div class="bladen-item">
                                    <img class="bladen-img" src="images/cement.png">
                                    <span class="bladen-title">Cement</span>
                                    <div class="bladen-info">
                                        <span class="bladen-pricem1">€130,- per m1</span><br>
                                        <span class="bladen-amount">Benodigde m1: 2.3m1</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €135,-</span>
                                    <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex">
                                <div class="bladen-item">
                                    <img class="bladen-img" src="images/old-wild-oak.png">
                                    <span class="bladen-title">Old Wild Oak</span>
                                    <div class="bladen-info">
                                        <span class="bladen-pricem1">€130,- per m1</span><br>
                                        <span class="bladen-amount">Benodigde m1: 2.3m1</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €135,-</span>
                                    <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h4 class="bladen-genre">Spoelbakken</h3>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex">
                                    <div class="bladen-item">
                                        <img class="bladen-img" src="images/spoelbak.png">
                                        <span class="bladen-title">Spoelbak 1</span>
                                        <div class="bladen-info"></div>
                                        <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €140,-</span>
                                        <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem">
                                    <div class="bladen-item selected">
                                        <img class="bladen-img" src="images/spoelbak.png">
                                        <span class="bladen-title">Spoelbak 2</span>
                                        <div class="bladen-info"></div>
                                        <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €240,-</span>
                                        <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <h4 class="bladen-genre">Kranen</h3>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex">
                                    <div class="bladen-item selected">
                                        <img class="bladen-img" src="images/kraan.png">
                                        <span class="bladen-title">Kraan 1</span>
                                        <div class="bladen-info"></div>
                                        <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €140,-</span>
                                        <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex">
                                    <div class="bladen-item ">
                                        <img class="bladen-img" src="images/kraan.png">
                                        <span class="bladen-title">Kraan 2</span>
                                        <div class="bladen-info"></div>
                                        <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €240,-</span>
                                        <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-griditem display-flex">
                                    <div class="bladen-item ">
                                        <img class="bladen-img" src="images/kraan.png">
                                        <span class="bladen-title">Kraan 3</span>
                                        <div class="bladen-info"></div>
                                        <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €240,-</span>
                                        <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- Einde STAP 3 blok -->
```

Comment: Can you please add more code and create a snippet? We need to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay so i added the whole piece of html. this issue repeats itself in multiple columns like this. There is no css that interferes with the bootstrap classes just to make things clear.

Comment: Thanks. Now, what's the problem?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the div items need to be in 2 columns on mobile phone. this gets overwritten by .row>*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you don't understand how Bootstrap grid system works.

This...

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">...</div>
```

...is the same as if you would write this.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">...</div>
```

If you want to have 2 columns on mobile, you need to add the class `col-6`.

See the snippet below.

```css
.row > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
  margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12" id="stap-3">
  <!-- STAP 3 blok -->
  <div class="stappen-block">
    <div class="text-stappen">
      <h1>STAP 3: Kies Bladen, spoelbak en kraan</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed auctor cras est, amet
        quis in. Semper vitae ultricies commodo et, commodo vitae in ut nulla. Tellus
        sapien sed elementum, eu et ut ac nisi ut. Nam urna porta turpis turpis volutpat
        ac pellentesque suscipit. Porta feugiat a in urna.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h4 class="bladen-genre">Bladen</h4>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem display-flex">
        <div class="bladen-item selected">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/licht-beton.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Licht Beton</span>
          <div class="bladen-info">
            <span class="bladen-pricem1">€130,- per m1</span><br>
            <span class="bladen-amount">Benodigde m1: 2.3m1</span>
          </div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €135,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem display-flex">
        <div class="bladen-item">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/donker-beton.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Donker Beton</span>
          <div class="bladen-info">
            <span class="bladen-pricem1">€130,- per m1</span><br>
            <span class="bladen-amount">Benodigde m1: 2.3m1</span>
          </div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €135,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem display-flex">
        <div class="bladen-item">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/cement.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Cement</span>
          <div class="bladen-info">
            <span class="bladen-pricem1">€130,- per m1</span><br>
            <span class="bladen-amount">Benodigde m1: 2.3m1</span>
          </div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €135,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem display-flex">
        <div class="bladen-item">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/old-wild-oak.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Old Wild Oak</span>
          <div class="bladen-info">
            <span class="bladen-pricem1">€130,- per m1</span><br>
            <span class="bladen-amount">Benodigde m1: 2.3m1</span>
          </div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €135,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h4 class="bladen-genre">Spoelbakken</h4>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem display-flex">
        <div class="bladen-item">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/spoelbak.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Spoelbak 1</span>
          <div class="bladen-info"></div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €140,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem">
        <div class="bladen-item selected">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/spoelbak.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Spoelbak 2</span>
          <div class="bladen-info"></div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €240,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h4 class="bladen-genre">Kranen</h4>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem display-flex">
        <div class="bladen-item selected">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/kraan.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Kraan 1</span>
          <div class="bladen-info"></div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €140,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem display-flex">
        <div class="bladen-item ">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/kraan.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Kraan 2</span>
          <div class="bladen-info"></div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €240,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 col-griditem display-flex">
        <div class="bladen-item ">
          <img class="bladen-img" src="images/kraan.png">
          <span class="bladen-title">Kraan 3</span>
          <div class="bladen-info"></div>
          <span class="bladen-price">Prijs: €240,-</span>
          <div class="button-holder"><a class="bladen-button">selecteer</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Einde STAP 3 blok -->
```

Comment: Thanks, i had a long break from front-end. I feel kind stupid for asking this, i've shouldve known.

Comment: You're welcome. :) There's no such thing as a stupid question. You don't have to feel bad about it.